# Is it possible to find a function if we know its differential?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Not something we were taught at uni yet, just something that peaked my curiosity.

If I was given a derivative of a scalar function, for example $f'(x)=x$ then I know that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ (let's just simplify and say $c=0$).

I can do this for all scalar functions, if the derivative is integratable.

What about non scalar functions however?

if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is not known to us, but we know its differential, $D_f$ which is an $n$ by $n$ matrix.

Is it possible to find $f$ if we know $D_f$? when can we? when cant we?

Comment: $D_f$ is the directional derivative, correct?

Comment: It might be, since $Df$ is composed of the partial derivatives of the function which allow you to obtain a lot.

Comment: It's impressive that you can do it for all $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ already

Comment: @user139388 I think the OP means by integrable, has an anti-derivative, otherwise in the one dimensional case $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ .

Comment: Well, theoretically, if $f'(x)$ is integratable, then an integral exists and it is possible to find $f$. not sure about the multidimensional case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is generally possible. You integrate in essentially the same way. For example suppose that $$\nabla f(x,y)=(1,1)$$ Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$$ so $$f(x,y)=x+\phi(y)$$ where $\phi$ is the "constant" of integration. Now, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0+\phi'(y)=1$$ so we must have $$\phi(y)=y+c$$ $c$ an arbitrary constant. Therefore the general function is $$f(x,y)=x+y+c$$ If you had a vector-valued function, you would treat each of the gradients in the matrix separately to find each component.

Comment: in your case, $f$ was from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. would it remain the same if $f$'s codomain was $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: "Generally possible" is a bit of an overstatement. In order to be integrable $Df$'s derivatives must satisfy equality of mixed partials, i.e. in the case of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $Df$ must be curl-free. If your domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not all of it, there are additional topological considerations. It's safe to say that it is usually *not* possible to integrate up $f$.

Comment: I am aware that the field must be conservative. The OP said that $Df$ was given, so I assumed they meant that a function's derivative was provided, and the goal was to recover $f$. Perhaps I misinterpreted the question though... thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If $f=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m): \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, then $D_f$ is an $m\times n$ matrix whose rows are $\nabla f_1, \nabla f_2,\dots,\nabla f_m$. Now if we know that the rows of $D_f$ are the functions $g_1,\dots,g_m$ then finding $f$ amounts to solving the following system of partial differential equations (PDEs):
\begin{align}
\nabla f_1 &= g_1 \\
\nabla f_2 &= g_2 \\
&\cdots \\
\nabla f_m &= g_m.
\end{align}
Although this is a system of equations, we can solve each equation independent of the others since each coordinate function $f_i$ is independent of the other coordinate functions. In summary, if we knew how to answer the following question we could answer your original question:

> Given a function $g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, does there exist a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that $\nabla f=g$?

In general, the answer to this question is "no". A vector field $g$ which is the gradient of some function is called [conservative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), and most vector fields are not conservative. When $n=3$, for example, a necessary condition that a vector field $f$ be conservative is that $\nabla\times f=0$.

There's probably more to be said on this question, but *I* can't say it because I'm not very familiar with PDEs. In any case, your problem does not always have a solution. For example, the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-y & x \\ x & y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not the derivative of any function because the vector field $(x,y)\mapsto(-y,x)$ is not conservative.